# Problem with Animating on local position Unity

Tags: unity, animation

Currently, I am having a Cube that needs to be animated to roll on its edge. Using unity built-in animation feature, I created 4 animations (`RotateUp`, `RotateDown`, `RotateLeft`, `RotateRight`). At the end of each animation I would put an Event to call a method on my script. To be able to move the object every time the animation is played, I put the cube with animator attached inside a parent object.
Below is the script attached to my cube.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RedCubeBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{


    Animator anim;

    bool isMoveTriggered = false;


    void Start()
    {
        anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            MoveUp();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            MoveDown();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            MoveLeft();
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            MoveRight();
        }

        if (isMoveTriggered)
        {
            if (IsBackToIdle())
            {
                transform.parent.position = transform.position;
                transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                isMoveTriggered = false;
            }
        }
    }


    void AnimationFinished()
    {

        anim.Play("IdleState");

    }

    public void MoveUp()
    {
        if (isMoveTriggered)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("MoveUp");
            isMoveTriggered = true;
            anim.Play("RotateUp");
        }
    }

    public void MoveDown()
    {
        if (isMoveTriggered)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("MoveDown");
            isMoveTriggered = true;
            anim.Play("RotateDown");
        }
    }


    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        if (isMoveTriggered)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("MoveLeft");
            isMoveTriggered = true;
            anim.Play("RotateLeft");
        }
    }

    public void MoveRight()
    {
        if (isMoveTriggered)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("MoveRight");
            isMoveTriggered = true;
            anim.Play("RotateRight");

        }
    }


    bool IsBackToIdle()
    {
        return anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("IdleState");
    }



}
```

Every time the arrow key is pressed the object would rotate but in the end when `AnimationFinished()` is called, the cube would just roll back to its starting position (because of playing `IdleState`). It will only work (the object didn't return to its starting position) if I pressed the arrow twice quickly.

I've tried to not call the `IdleState` (which is only an empty state), but what happens next is it just won't play another animation again when triggered.

[image]

What should I do in order to get it work without having to press the key twice?

Comment: I think cube rolling does not have idle state. Instead it has connections from anystate to every rotation. And rotation must be a complete rotation showing all 4 sides up in correct order. Was that understandable?